# From piecewise linear convex to strictly convex

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Suppose that $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is a piecewise linear convex function. Each linear piece is supposed to have a different slope than the other ones.

Can you describe using "classical functions" (polynomials, exponential...) a "simple function" $\bar{f}$ that would be strictly convex and passing through all the summits of $f$?

Comment: what do you mean by summits of $f$? non-differentiable points,   right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: convolute it with $x^2$

You can think about both integral convolution and infimal convolution .